# Is there any benefit to specifying the path & address to the current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am editing some old code, and came across a line which puzzled me. The code in question copies some data from one workbook to another and begins with defining the two workbook-objects the code will work on. The two lines looks something like this:

```
Set wbFra = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name)
Set wbTil = Workbooks.Open("https://nhy.sharepoint.com/teams/Team-xxxxxx/xxxx/xxx/Someworkbook.xlsx", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Now what's puzzling me is the first line. Is there any benefit to typing out the entire path to the workbook instead of just using `Set wbFrom = ThisWorkbook`? Why did the original author even attempt to open the workbook in which the code resides? Is there any benefit to this?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't have 2 workbooks with same name opened at same time in Excel. I don't know how is the rest of the code, but executing `Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name)` will open a workbook that is already opened. It does not arise any error?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The code works just fine. I just found the syntax weird and wondered if there could be any reason why it was written the way it was. It is also not trying to open a different file with the same name, it is trying to open the workbook the code resides in. I assume the Workbooks.Open method just returns the already open workbook in cases where it is already open.

Comment: I did a test replying code. When VBa executes line `Set wbFra = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name)` It pops up an alert, asking if you want to *reopen* the file (but loosing all changes made since last saving). If I click on *NO*, it raises an error on `Workbooks.Open`. If I click *Yes*, the workbook is closed and opened. Maybe original coder was trying to *Reload* everything? Maybe some parts are data conections and reopening makes some part an update or something? But in any case, it's pretty weird.

Comment: Yup, thus this question :-) What's more weird is that I don't get that message when I execute the code :-p @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: If you don't get that message, it means somewhere before that code there is a line  `Application.DisplayAlerts=False`. When it is `False` it will autoacept the *Yes* option. So the workbook *autoreopens*. Maybe original developer wanted to autocalculate **everything** without using several lines of code to update databases connections, formulas, PivotTables, and so on. Several objects in Excel can be set up to autoupdate when opening file (Pivot tables), and maybe with VBA in the `Workbook_Open` event there are some updates too, so with that line, original Dev wanted to *update everything*

Comment: It's literally the fifth line in the macro, which I am running by itself to easier see what happens. No changing of application settings before it, and printing Application.DisplayAlerts gives me true. @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Answer (score 0):

Actually this line

```
Set wbFra = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name)
```

doesn't make much sense, because it will open the workbook this code is in and therefore this workbook is already open.

```
Set wbFra = ThisWorkbook
```

would have the same result (and is the recommended approach).

---

A bit off-topic here but …

… instead of hard coding the backslash `"\"` as path separator I recommend to use `Application.PathSeparator` so it works also in MacOS.

Comment: Yes, that is the basis of my question. You are saying that there is no benefit, or even point, to  what the original author did?

Comment: @eirikdaude yes, I recommend the second approach. First doesn't make any sense. I only see disadvantages.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Saying that they both end up in the same result doesn't really answer why they should or shouldn't use that method

Comment: @Tom `Workbooks.Open` is to open a workbook that is not opened yet. And `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name` refers to the workbook that runs the actual code (which means it is already open). So how much sense does it make trying to open a workbook that is definitly already open if you can access this directly?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I agree, it doesn't make sense to do it, but the code still accepts it and runs. `Workbooks.Open` takes a string to the path, then opens the workbook (if it is not already open) and returns the workbook object. If the workbook is already open it returns that workbook object. So whilst it doesn't really make sense to do it, it still returns the workbook object. Which ultimately is what we are trying to achieve. I'd say the main benefit to using `Set wbFra = ThisWorkbook` is speed. You achieve the same result in almost an immeasurable time whereas using `Workbooks.Open` takes ~0.5s.

Comment: @Tom Exactly what I told. Both end up with the same thing. Actually did you make any measurements? I couldn't encounter any differences in speed between both methods. In Excel 2016 at least both just return the reference to the actual workbook immediateley. So actually I see no point where this doesn't answer the question. The first one is just more like `a = 1 + 1 + 5 - 5` where the second one is `a = 2`. Both work, both end up the same result. If you run them 10 million times the second one might end up being faster.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I did - In my copy of Excel 2016 I was getting 0 back for just setting it to `ThisWorkbook` (as kind of expected) and ~0.5s back when using `Workbooks.Open` (Did repeat test a few times). However, I didn't feel like it was enough information to give an answer. I don't think it answers the question because OP already knows it doesn't really make sense. But is curious as to why someone has done it. Saying it doesn't make sense isn't really answering it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The only reason why that I could come with to not do it (as it can result in the desired result) is the speed of running it and also if `ThisWorkbook` is not saved it will error.

Comment: @Tom Well, I aggree on that. But then there might be no possible anwser to that question, eg if the actual reason (why someone did it the first way) is because he had no idea what he actually was doing ;) Which we have to consider as an option too.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ -  I can agree with that :P